# Как передать значение во внешнюю переменную?

Tags: javascript

Помогите розобраться с этими промисами и асинхроностью)) Уже сил нету)

Описание:

Проект на котором практикуюсь - простой лендинг, на котором есть карточки, которые получаем с сервера (файла) в формате `json`.
С этими карточками делаем различные действия: генерируются слайдеры, генерируется каталог карточек,
так же  при клике на карточку генирируется модальное окно, с данными из того же `json` файла. Всего карточек порядка 10-20 штук.

И что хотелось бы сделать - получить все данные из json файла и поместить их в глобальную переменную, чтобы не делать множество запросов к серверу, а только один и после использовать
просто переменную, в которой хранится вся информация.

И здесь у меня проблемы) Я могу делать запрос, получать промис, парсить его, получать данные и сразу же с ними работать (например передать в функцию, которая будет рендерить карточки на странице).

Так же я могу передать полученые данные в переменную `cards`, но у меня не получается имортировать (передать) эту переменную в глобальную область видимости - в файл `main.js` (получаю `undefined`), что-бы ее можно было передавать в любую функцию.

Не могу понять что происходит, передается пустая переменная, так как асинхронный код еще не выполнился, или промис, который не может отработать?

Я просто хочу получить данные от сервера, поместить их в переменную, передать в глобальную область видимости и использовать их. Но так как получение асинхронное, то как гарантировать, что когда я где-то буду использовать переменную она уже будет иметь данные?

Модуль запроса

```
const getResourse = async (url) => {
  let res = await fetch(url);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Could not fetch ${url}, status: ${res.status}`);
  }
  return await res.json();
};

export { getResourse };
```

Модуль в котором пулучаю данные и записываю в переменную.

```
import { getResourse } from '../services/request';
let cards;  //переменная для хранения данных
const getCards = (url) => {
  getResourse(url)
    .then(res => {
      cards = res;  // присваем получиные данные переменной
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(cards);  //все работает данные получены.
  }, 2000);
}
export default getCards;
```

Главный файл

```
import getCards from "./modules/getCards";

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  'use strict';

  getCards('./resources/db/cards.json');
});
```

В main.js я пыталась и переменные создавать, и передавать в них функцию, и импортировать переменную, и через setTimeOut выводить но ничего не получилось)

Comment: Не очень пойму про что речь, но вижу then. привет микрозадача. Читаем синхронный код, выполняем микро задачу, выполняем макро задачу. Любой then, это promise, точнее можно его вернуть, как простую функцию возвращаете. Потом где нужно используете функцию, можете в переменную запихнуть, не суть, но важно. что микро задача останется микро задачей и чудес никаких не будет. Асинхронный код не превратится в синхронный. Я к тому, что  `global.then(то, что вернул последний then из прошлого файла а тот - resolve => console.log(то, что вернул последний then из прошлого файла а тот - resolve)`

Comment: @WalkMess подробнее описала вопрос, подскажите пожалуйста)